# Matlab: imcrop throws error while C code generation

Tags: matlab, matlab-coder

in matlab while compiling to c code imcrop failed to run.
is there is any alternative method or any way to suppress?

I am using Matlab2016a. Below is code snippet:

```
if ~isempty(bbox);
    bbox = bbox(1,1:4);
    Ic = imcrop(im,bbox);
    bboxeye = step(faceDetectorLeye, Ic);
end
```

Edit:
fullcode

```
function signal = detectFatigue(im)

% Create a detector object
faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('ClassificationModel','FrontalFaceLBP','MinSize',[100 100]);
faceDetectorLeye = vision.CascadeObjectDetector('EyePairBig');

% Detect faces
bbox = step(faceDetector, im);

if ~isempty(bbox);
bbox = bbox(1,1:4);
Ic = imcrop(im,bbox);
bboxeye = step(faceDetectorLeye, Ic);

if ~isempty(bboxeye);
    bboxeye = bboxeye(1,1:4);
    Eeye = imcrop(Ic,bboxeye);
    [~, nce, ~ ] = size(Eeye);
    % Divide into two parts
    Leye = Eeye(:,1:round(nce/2),:);
    Reye = Eeye(:,round(nce/2+1):end,:);

    % make grascale
    Leye = rgb2gray(Leye);
    Reye = rgb2gray(Reye);

    Leye = filterim(Leye);
    Reye = filterim(Reye);

    lroi = [ 12 5 30 16 ];
    rroi = [ 18 5 30 16 ];
    Leyeroi = imcrop(Leye,lroi);
    Reyeroi = imcrop(Reye,rroi);

    [lc, ~ ] = findcircle(Leyeroi);
    [rc, ~ ] = findcircle(Reyeroi);
    if isempty(lc) && isempty(rc)
        signal = 1;
    else
        signal = 0;
    end
end
end

function Leye=filterim(Leye)
    se = strel('disk',2,4);
    % dilate graysacle
    Leye = imdilate(Leye,se);
    % erode grayscale
    Leye = imerode(Leye,se);            
    Leye = imadjust(Leye);
    Leye = imcomplement(Leye);
    Leye = im2bw(Leye,0.95);
    Leye =  imresize(Leye,[30 60]);

function [c, r] = findcircle(Leyeroi)
    [c ,r ] = imfindcircles(Leyeroi,[5 9],'ObjectPolarity','bright','Sensitivity',0.95);
    [rm,id] = max(r);
    r = rm;
    c = c(id,:);
    if ~isempty(c)
        c(1) = c(1) + 15;
        c(2) = c(2) + 7;    
    end
```

and to test the detectFatigue.m below is the function

```
function  testdetectFatigue()

vid=webcam(1);
for loop=1:10
im=snapshot(vid);
detectFatigue(im);
end
```

Comment: That `imcrop` call should work. What is the error? What is the size of the image and what are the values of `bbox`?

Comment: the error is : "Function call failed." specifying the line number.
Image size is 480x 640 x 3, and bbox size is 1 x 4.

Comment: Code generation toolbox does not support indexed images neither it supports interactive syntax.  Send us the image and matlab code, so I could suggest what is proper solution for this problem.

Comment: @HarshalZope But what are the contents of `bbox`? Are the values within range?

Comment: @beaker bbox = [ 120 140 200 200] and this is valid values.